# Boost Json string storage and pointers

Tags: c++, boost

Hoping for some C++ advise to check my understanding. I am learning to use the Boost C++ json package and curious how the following example code uses memory. There is a copy of the string "Boost" in the json value variable jv. When running this code do three copies of the string "boost" occur for the print out in the print function? OR is this all done via pointers? At what point are string copies destroyed? Is there an more efficient way to just use pointers to the original string in jv?

```
void PrintCstring(const char* c_string) {
    std::cout << c_string << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    value jv = {
    { "pi", 3.141 },
    { "happy", true },
    { "name", "Boost" },
    { "nothing", nullptr },
    { "answer", {
        { "everything", 42 } } },
    {"list",{1, 0, 2} },
    {"object", {
        { "currency", "USD" },
        { "value", 42.99 }
            } }
    };

    std::cout << jv << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << jv.at("name").as_string().c_str() << std::endl;
    PrintCstring(jv.at("name").as_string().c_str());
    return 0;
}    
Output:
    Boost
    Boost
```